# Send data from php to c++ using tcp socket

Tags: php, c++, sockets

I'm trying to send data from my simple php script to c++ programm, thad uses socket but I can't to reproduce this data correctly.
My simple PHP script:

```
$motorPort = fsockopen("192.168.2.1", 4444, $errno, $errstr, 30);
fwrite($motorPort, '0100');

sleep(5);

fclose($motorPort);
```

My C++ code:

```
...
unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
...
ssize_t count = recv(client_handle, &buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
...
unsigned int cmd;
unsigned long commands_count = count/4;
for(cmd = 0; cmd != commands_count; ++cmd)
{
    printf("Buffer = %d\n", buffer[0]);
    printf("Buffer = %d\n", buffer[1]);
    printf("Buffer = %d\n", buffer[2]);
    printf("Buffer = %d\n", buffer[3]);
}
...
```

But I get:
48
49
48
48
Instead:
0
1
0
0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending ascii and expecting binary. http://www.ascii.cl/ ascii 48 `0` ascii 49 `1`

I haven't done it myself, so I'm not sure of the details. But you probably need to use `pack()`

Comment: Yes! You are right! For my case I use pack("c*", 0,1,0,0)